# How to copy a file to output folder without modifications? Visual C#

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to publish a project with a mp3 file in the application folder, so that I can use it when app is running. Is there some way to do it?

My current attempt is to click on the mp3 and drag it to the "Solution Explorer". When the program is published, the output folder does have a "play.mp3" file, but it is named "play.mp3.deploy", which turns it unusable

Comment: how do you publish the web site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a forms app then add the mp3 file to a resource file (resx) and access it that way.

If the app is a website you should be able to mark the file properties as Build Action = Content and Copy To Output Directory = Copy Always. This should then just get deployed in the same manner a js file would for example.

Comment: How can I access a resource file? Yes this is a form app

Comment: VS auto generates a load of access code for resource files so they are very easy to work with. Just Google "Visual Studio Resource File" and you will find plenty of examples.